# Add a number from right to left in the decimal value using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field where by default I will have $0.00.

- when I enter a number, say 1, the input should show $0.01,
- again if I enter 2, the input should show $0.12
- simultaneously if I press 3, 4, 5, the final output should be $123.45.
- Now, If I click delete, it should remove 5, so output will be $123.4
- again if I click delete it should remove 4, so output will be $123
- If I add a number 2 again here, it should show, $123.2

Is it possible? I am stuck at the last 3 steps.
I have this so far,

```
let previousTip = 0;
const addingFunction = (value) => {
    if(Number(value) <= Number(previousTip)) return Number(value).toFixed(2);
    const addNumberRightToLeft = (baseValue, updatedValue) => ((baseValue * 10) + (updatedValue / 100)).toFixed(2);
    previousTip = addNumberRightToLeft((Number(previousTip) || 0), value.length > 1 ? value.slice(-1) : value);
    return previousTip;
}
```

my onClick event has

```
const tipString = addingFunction(e?.target?.value?.trim()?.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') || '');
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: You should make a switch statement on e.target -> if it is a backspace keyboard hit, delete last integer

Comment: `$0.00` is a string or a number that you convert after to a string?

Comment: @nico263nico it is a number, I just added $ in description for info purpose

Comment: You are calling this "onClick", but on click of what? Because it's not at all clear what `e.target.value` would be.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two functions that should do what you need. You can call the correct one depending on which key is pressed on `onKeyPressed`

I'm currently not able to test this, but the logic is there.

```
function addValueToNumber(number,value){
count = 0;
while (number%10 != 0){
    number *= 10;
    count ++;
}
number += value/10;
for (i=0,i<count-1,i++){
    number /= 10;
}
}

function remove(number){
    count = 0;
    while (number%10 != 0){
       number *= 10;
       count ++;
    }
    number = number//10;
    for (i=0,i<count-1,i++){
       number /= 10;
    }
}
```